# Android x86 Virtual box with Internet and connection to adb?

Tags: networking, android-x86, virtualization

I have **Android x86 4.2** Installed on my **Virtual Box**.
My main purpose is debug with eclipse and get internet on Android

Some how i am able to get **internet** and also able to connect from **adb** (of **ADT**) but not both at a time

i have tried several combination to get both but no luck

### How i get Internet

```
I get internet when i use NAT in one of these 4 adapters
```

### How i get connected with adb

```
I get connected with adb when connected to newly created Host Only adapter 

note: the default host only adapter was not working
```

I have two questions:

First is **how i will get both The Internet and connection to adb**
Second is Can i get my **bluetooth** and **Wifi** device **available** to My Virtual box Android

### Note: My Internet connection type is either 3G HSUPA using Modem or WiFi no LAN

**Note:** when both of them are connected then either of them works not both I have googled, Stacked, Virtual box site too but no luck
Initially i was unable to connect to adb but I figured out the way i can!
Please any one know the issue.

[image: NAT For Internet]

[image: Host Only Adapter #2]

Comment: 0000000000000000000

Answer (score 3):

I'm using the very same setup with NAT mode. To connect via ADB:

1. in *VirtualBox Manager*, right-click on your VM and select "show log"
2. press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> to initialize a search, type "DHCP". You will find several lines stating something like `NAT: DHCP offered IP address 10.0.2.15` – that's your IP, write it down ;)
3. select the "gear icon" in the same context menu to "change settings"
4. go to the "network" tab, and click the "port forwarding" button
5. add two rules to forward ports 5555 (adb) and 5554 (console) from the guest to your host machine. To make an easy rule for potential multiple Android-VMs, you can simply add a digit to the end – e.g. 5555→55551 and 5554→55541 for this machine (add a "2" for your second, if any).
6. now on your host machine, execute the command `adb connect localhost:55551`

Done. Execute any ADB commands as usual. You can use `adb disconnect localhost:55551` if it gets in the way (e.g. if you're using some other device, and don't want to always specify which one to use with each ADB command).

Answer (score 2):

In case someone finds this thread: Use bridge mode, you will get an IP adress from your LAN.

To do so:

1. in *VirtualBox Manager*, select your VM and click the "gear icon" (change settings)
2. select the networking tab
3. in the first drop-down box, select "bridge mode"

Comment: So how do you set up this bridge mode?

Comment: @DanHulme OP knows where to find it (same place he'd switched between NAT and Host Only). I've added it, though :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you check with netcfg within Android that both are really up? If, e.g., eth1 is down, enable it with `netcfg eth1 dhcp up`.